# How to make react-valid code (add inner script)

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, ref, script-tag

I need to change this code to make it valid for React

```
<script src="https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/html/payForm/js/tinkoff_v2.js"></script>
<form name="TinkoffPayForm" onsubmit="pay(this); return false;">
  <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="terminalkey" value="TinkoffBankTest">
  <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="frame" value="true">
  <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="language" value="ru"> 
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Сумма заказа" name="amount" required>
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Номер заказа" name="order">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Описание заказа" name="description">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="ФИО плательщика" name="name">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Контактный телефон" name="phone">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="submit" value="Оплатить">
</form>
```

I added `<script>` to `index.html`, created `<form>` in React Component and add **ref** to form

I created `const w = window as any` and added

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    w.pay(form.current);
  }
```

But it didn't work

What I need to pass as argument to w.pay function?

Comment: I can't read the language, but a cursory Google search finds what appears to be [a React component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinkoff-pay) for the library you're using.  Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: https://github.com/JsusDev/react-tinkoff-pay 404error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`